# Displaying Scrapy Results to User in Django

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I'm VERY new to Python and I'm attempting to integrate Scrapy with Django.

Here is what I'm trying to make happen:

1. User submits URL to be scraped
2. URL is scraped
3. Scraped data is returned in screen to user
4. User assigns attributes (if necessary) then saves it to database.

What is the best way to accomplish this? I've played with Django Dynamic Scraper, but I think I'm better off maintaining control over Scrapy for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

holding on django request while scraping another website may not be the best idea, this flow is better done asynchronously, meaning, release django request and have another process to handle the scrapying, I guess its not an easy thing to achieve for newcomers, but try to bear with me.

flow should look like this:

1. user submit a request to scrape some data from another website
2. spider crawl start on a different process than django, user request is released
3. spider pipelines items to some data store (database)
4. the user loop on asking for that data, django update the user based on the data inserted to the data store

shooting a scrapy spider can be done by launching it straight from python code, using a tool like [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), also see [django and celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/django/first-steps-with-django.html), or by launching it in a new process using python's `subprocess`, or even better, using [scrapyd](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to manage those spiders

Comment: Interesting! Since I'm new and quite ignorant about programming, I hadn't thought about each being requests. I'll have to better familiarize my self with this concept. 


If I'm understanding you correctly, this would mean that the data would be sent straight to the database (not assigning the attributes, as needed, first). The data would then be called back into a django view where the user can manipulate/verify the data and set the attributes needed (so basically, the items would have those attributes as empty strings or null until it was called back into the view)

Comment: yes, in such scenario I guess the page would be gradually built, or there would be a flag that mark that the data is ready, in any case communication between the spider and webserver should be through the database and the server should request data periodically, also note that if the user closes the browser it does not change the flow and the data can wait for him for latter use

Comment: Could you potentially point me in the direction of how to flag that data in django? Even just the term names to look through in the docs/google. One last note: since I don't want this data to be apart of a larger system until it has been analyzed, would it be smarter to have a boolean called "analyzed", or have them in some sort of separate table?

Comment: first note that calling the database from django is initiated **only** by the user, meaning a call coming from the user browser, django is not initiating or processing anything, just pull the data from the database when the user ask for it, all cleaning matching changing and analyzing is done by scrapy, other than that see how scrapy can play well with django here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/djangoitem.html

Comment: If you're going to do it async, you may be better off with the tornado framework: http://www.tornadoweb.org/‎